# Pandas to_datetime() not working with date comparison

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I was querying a dataframe based on the InvoiceDate column and when I tried to extract all the rows for a particular date --> sales_data[sales_data["InvoiceDate"].dt.date == "2011-06-22"]. It returned an empty dataframe, which was not expected. Therefore, I tried running some experiments of my own as shown below:

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = "2009-12-01 07:45:00"
d2 = "2009-12-01 08:20"
d1 = pd.to_datetime(d1)
d2 = pd.to_datetime(d2)
print(d1 == d2)
print(d1.year == d2.year)
print(d1.month == d2.month)
print(d1.day == d2.day)
print(d1.date == d2.date)
```

The output was as follows:
[image: Output]

Everything is correct except the last line. Why is the other code working but the date comparison is giving output as false?

Comment: Your unexpected result is not related to `pd.to_datetime`. Instead, `date` is not a timestamp attribute, it's a method. So the last line should be `print(d1.date() == d2.date())`. Once you call the method, results are equal as expected.

Comment: @FObersteiner 
This works, thanks. But how do I extract all values(rows) in a dataframe that correspond to a specific date? Like the one I have posted in the question description

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        '2009-12-01 07:45:00',
        '2009-12-01 08:20',
        '2009-12-02 08:20',
    ],
    columns=['date'],
)
df.date = df.date.map(pd.to_datetime)

my_date = pd.to_datetime('2009-12-01')

df[df.date.apply(lambda x: x.date() == my_date.date())]
```

Output:

```
                 date
0 2009-12-01 07:45:00
1 2009-12-01 08:20:00
```